# StartFlipping for ViewFlipper after 60seconds from last touch

Tags: android, touch, viewflipper

My app contains a `ViewFlipper` with some images. when app starts, the `ViewFlipper` `startflipping()`. When user touch the screen `ViewFlipper stopflipping()`. I must do that after 60 seconds from last touch, ViewFlipper to start again flipping. My class implements `onTouchListener` and I have this method `onTouch`:

```
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {


        switch (arg1.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

            downXValue = arg1.getX();
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

            currentX = arg1.getX();


            if (downXValue < currentX) {
                // Set the animation
                vf.stopFlipping();
                vf.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.push_right_out));
                vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.push_right_in));
                // Flip!
                vf.showPrevious();
            }


            if (downXValue > currentX) {
                // Set the animation
                vf.stopFlipping();
                vf.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.push_left_out));
                vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.push_left_in));
                // Flip!
                vf.showNext();
            }

            if (downXValue == currentX) {
                final int idImage = arg0.getId();

                vf.stopFlipping();
                System.out.println("id" + idImage);
                System.out.println("last touch "+getTimeOfLastEvent());

            }
            break;
        }
        }

        // if you return false, these actions will not be recorded
        return true;
    }
```

and I found this method, for finding time of the last touch :

```
static long timeLastEvent=0;
public long getTimeOfLastEvent() {

        long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeLastEvent;
        timeLastEvent = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return duration;
    }
```

My question is : where should I call the `getTimeOfLastEvent()` ? If I put it on `onTouch()` I will never catch the moment when getTimeOfLastEvent==60000, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you should do is create a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) (should be an instance variable of your `Activity` and should be initialized during `onCreate`):

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler();
```

Also you will need a `Runnable` that can start the flipping again (also needs to be declared within your `Activity`):

```
private Runnable flipController = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    vf.startFlipping();
  }
};
```

Then in your `onClick` you just post the `Runnable` on the `Handler` but delayed by 60 seconds:

```
myHandler.postDelayed( flipController, 60000 );
```

Posting it delayed means: "Run this code in 60 seconds".