# How to create a simple screensaver in Android?

Tags: android, service, screensaver

I want to create a simple screensaver in android:
I have one simple question:

How to detect the time  user last touched the screen. In order to display the screensaver after a user defined length of time.Please help I am new to this?

Comment: Possibly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295113/startflipping-for-viewflipper-after-60seconds-from-last-touch

Comment: LCD/AMOLED screens do not need “saving”—the battery needs it more.

Answer (score 0):

Start a timer from here:
[onUserInteraction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29)